# Reduce Generics in class declaration

Tags: c#, generics

I'm stuck with a C# syntax problem

I would like to abstract my code a little bit and i go to something like that :

```
public abstract class DMO<TDao ,TExtender>
            where TDao : Dao
            where TExtender : Extender<TDao>
{
     abstract Dictionary<TExtender, PropertyInfo> Properties { get; set; }
....
}
```

just because if i do that

```
public abstract class DMO<TDao>
            where TDao : Dao
{
     abstract Dictionary<Extender<TDao>, PropertyInfo> Properties { get; set; }
....
}
```

I'm not able to use a derived of `Extender<TDao>`

Is there any way to make that simpler (I'm stuck with .net 3.5, so i think i can't use covariant for that)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe a little elaboration on what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The question is about reducing class complexity, by reducting generic parameters amount,  i have some issue understanding why i need TExender here, considering than TExtender is just an Extender<TDAo> but after some esearch it could be just a framework limitation and could be solved by using covariant generics (but only with .net 4.0)

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot use the derived class of Extender<TDao> in dictionary? I think that your 2nd case is good enough and should working well

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions that people reading your code will understand the purpose of these classes. It's hard to determine the solution if the purpose isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
public abstract class DMO<T> where T: Extender<Dao> {
    public abstract Dictionary<T, PropertyInfo> Properties {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note that `virtual` or `abstract` members cannot be private.

Comment: ok but i'm not sure that it work cause Dao is an abstract class and i need tthat Extender<Dao> to be used like Extender<DaoDerived>

Comment: Of course you can use any generic class like `Extender<DaoDerived>`, since `DaoDerived` would derive from `Dao` as you intended.